# Nightwatch.js method `.element()` returns "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am attempting to retrieve an element from a webpage using the Nightwatch `.element()` method:

```
browser.element('class name', 'story-share-tools', function (res) {  
  console.log(res);
});
```

The `res` parameter is being displayed in the console as `[object Object]` and doesn't appear to be a **WebElement JSON object**.

I need the actual HTML element `story-share-tools` that contains an unordered list with items I want to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit surprising because I do not have this problem with `.element()`: object details are displayed in my terminal. I assume you have an issue with `.toString()` somewhere. As you may know, in JavaScript, `[object Object]` is the string returned by `Object.prototype.toString()`.

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: 'Bar'
};

console.log(obj.toString());
```

So instead of doing this:

```
console.log(res);
```

Try this:

```
for (var prop in res) {
  if (res.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(prop, res[prop]);
  }
}
```